# Unable to align the second flexbox column to the left

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My problem is this: I have a flexbox that places a summary section and an image section in a row. The summary section is a nested flexbox that displays the 3 lists as the first column and the horizontal soiltype list as the second column. The problem is that the content of the second column is placed in the center while i want it to align to the left at the same starting position as the lists column above. Here is an image of the current situation:

[image]

I have tried using `justify-content: flex-start`, `align-items: flex-start`, `margin-left: 0px; margin-right: auto;` and `margin-left:-500px`, but everytime the second column remains fixed in the center. Can anyone please tell me what i should do to move the content of the second column to the right? Thank you,

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
        <div class="flexBox flexItem">
              <div class="summary">
                <div class="flexBox flexItem test">
              <ul class="details">
                <li><strong>Days until harvest:</strong>   {{seedDetails.growthTime}}</li>
                <li><strong>Required sun exposure:</strong> {{sunExposure}}</li>
                <li><strong>Plant height:</strong> {{seedDetails.plantHeight | measure : distancePipeArgument : true}}</li>
                <li><strong>Plant width:</strong> 15 inch</li>
              </ul>

              <ul class="details">
                <li><strong>Germinates after:</strong> 14 days</li>  
                <li><strong>Germination temperature:</strong> {{seedDetails.growthTemperature | measure: temperaturePipeArgument : true}}</li>
                <li><strong>Row spacing:</strong> {{seedDetails.rowSpacing | measure : distancePipeArgument : true}}</li>
                <li><strong>Plant spacing:</strong> {{seedDetails.plantSpacing | measure : distancePipeArgument : true}}</li>
              </ul>

              <ul class="details">
                <li><strong>Sow depth:</strong> {{seedDetails.sowDepth | measure : distancePipeArgument : true}}</li>
                <li><strong>Life cycle:</strong> {{seedDetails.lifeCycleType | titlecase}}</li> 
                <li><strong>Hardy at:</strong> {{seedDetails.hardiness | measure: temperaturePipeArgument : true}}</li>
                <li><strong>Maximum temperature:</strong> {{seedDetails.maximumTemperature | measure: temperaturePipeArgument : true}}</li>
              </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="soils">
                <ul>
                  <li class="inline"><strong>This plant grows well in:</strong></li><li class="inline">                                
                    <mat-chip-list> 
                    <mat-chip style="margin-right:8px; background-color:aquamarine;" *ngFor="let soilType of soilTypes" [selectable]="selectable" (click)="showDialog(soilType)">  
                        {{soilType}}
                    </mat-chip>  
                  </mat-chip-list></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
                <figure class="carousel">
                  <div class="crop shadow">
                  <input type="image" [src]="seedDetails.imagePreview" class="thumbnail" (click)="showDialog(image)"/>
                </div>
                  <small>Click to view full image</small>
                </figure>
          </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .flexItem {
        max-width: 1100px;
    }


    .flexBox{
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex; 
    }

    ul.details{
        margin-left: 0px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        flex: 1 1 300px;
    }


      .inline{
          display: inline-block; 
         }

      .soils{

            align-items: flex-start;
      }

  .summary{
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:column;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      align-items: flex-start;
      /* justify-content: flex-start;
      text-align: left; */
      width:85%;
      /* align-items: flex-start; */
      /* border: solid grey 1; */
  }

    .carousel{
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;
        /* overflow:hidden; */
        background-color: gray;
        flex: 1 1 250px;
        /* margin-left: 0px; */
    }

    .crop{
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    .shadow{
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
        border: 0.5px solid black;
    }

.test{
    width:850px;
    /* border: solid black; */
}
```

Comment: I tested this in a fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/0eknd2q4/ , and alignment seems to work fine. Note that I did add `.soils ul{margin: 0; padding: 0;}` to fully align left, but it is working otherwise. Do you have extra css code in `.flexBox` or `.flexItem` that you didn't give us?

Comment: @MikeDiglio i checked and i didn't miss any code mentions in those css classes. I checked if maybe this is some quirk in Google Chrome but its not because the same behavior is displayed in microsoft edge, so this is really strange. However your `.soils ul` solution does work when i also add `width:100%` to the `.soils` class. Everything works like a charm now. So thank you for your input. Its strange that adding `width:100%` somehow solves the problem because im not setting it anywhere else.

Comment: it is possible that the `width: 85%` from the `.summary` class was causing it to be pushed to the middle. In either case, glad you got it working